# How to Set Response In JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jQuery code to submit form data to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#update").click(function() {
            $.post("./Index/StatusUpdateDo",
                {
                    status: $("#status").val()
                },
                function(data, status) {
                    setTimeout(quit, 2000);
                });
        });
```

Also I have

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

in that same page. What i want to do is get server response and print on that 'div'. as I'm new to jquery please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) would have revealed that `.html()` assigns HTML content to an element and the front page of jquery.com shows that `$('#response')` selects an element by ID.

```
$('#response').html(data);
```

You put this code in the callback function where you currently call `setTimeout`.